Movie about a white horse and a prisoner
I can't remember the title of a movie which I watched many years ago (6 at least). That movie is a 3D animated movie [like a cartoon]. It was in English. The story was about an amazing horse (which I think was white). 
There was a man who was arrested as a prisoner and bound. A man (like an agent) was riding a horse. This horse didn't like that man and suddenly increased its speed, causing the man to fall down. He gets his gun and prepares to shoot this horse. The prisoner then cuts his ropes and saves the horse and jumped and ran with horse. I can't remember the middle but at the end the horse was followed with the intention to kill it. When they followed it, the horse jumped between 2 huge mountains unexpectedly. Everyone was surprised. But still there was a chance to shoot it and a one man aims a gun towards the horse to kill it but an agent stopped him and saluted the horse. That's almost how it started and ended but not exactly right.

Please narrow down "many years ago". What was the approximate year? Was it in English? Do you remember anything about the rest of the plot?

@Walt yes an english movie and at least 6 years ago.the movie was very beautiful .

This is likely the animated 2002 movie Spirit: Stallion of the Cimarron, only the horse there is light-brown. From IMDb:

The mustang stallion Spirit grows up to proudly succeed his father as leader of the Cimarron herd in the unspoiled Wild West. When 'civilization' reaches Dakota territory, naive curiosity gets him caught by cowboys and sold to the US Cavalry. Its method of training by breaking a horse fails utterly on him.

A colonel tries to ride Spirit, but it eventually throws him off in front of a captive Native American called Little Creek who's tied nearby. The colonel pulls out a pistol, intending to shoot Spirit, but Little Creek cuts the ropes that bind him, saves Spirit and they both escape. In the end, Spirit, fleeing the colonel, leaps over the Grand Canyon. This amazes the colonel, who stops one of his men from shooting Spirit with a rifle, nods to Spirit in respect and retreats to the cliffs. Here's the trailer:




yeah! that's what i was talking about.ohh i have forget it's color
